# String as Primary Key in Hibernate from oracle sequence

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

i have a oracle sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  HEALTH_MST_CHILD_SEQ  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 2 ;
```

Java Class (BO)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="HEALTH_MST_CHILD")
public class HealthMstChild {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="childHealthSeq",sequenceName="HEALTH_MST_CHILD_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="childHealthSeq")
        @Column(name="CHILD_ID")
        private String childId;
}
```

Oracle Sequence generate numeric value so it will raise me Exception

Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String

if there is any solution please help me.

Comment: May be you should use Integer to store an integer sequence value ?

Comment: i want to store sequence value as String and my datatype in oracle is varchar2.

Comment: Were you able to successfully implement this, for example by using the solution proposed by SimpleOne?

Comment: I found this really flexible and sophisticated solution, and was able to use parts of it to solve my own problem today: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-a-custom-string-based-sequence-identifier-generator-with-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

Try `to_char` function.

E.g. `sequence_no` is the integer column that has the sequence value:

```
sequence_value_char = to_char(sequence_no);
```

Then use `sequence_value_char` in your code.